# Under what conditions is it possible to ionize atoms using an electron gun?

Tags: electrons, plasma-physics

Using the electron bombardment method, if I wanted to ionize, for example, Xenon gas electrons with an electron gun, under what conditions is it possible to do so? (Heat, pressure?)

Comment: Do you mean ionize Xeon gas atoms? If yes, then by many methods that achieve the necessary energy of approximately 12 eV.

Comment: Could you describe some? I know this is done in vacuum televisions.

Comment: Are you looking for the principle of a [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray)?

Comment: What is the principle?

Answer (score -1):

I know you can ionize air with a laser leaving an ion trail for electricity to travel in a strait line called laser filamentation and it has been used to catch lightning and the US army has experimented with it as a weapon.

[image]
https://www.wired.com/2009/04/armys-multimo-1/

[image]
https://www.sciencenews.org/article/bolt-above